# remaking code from in the same function doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

On the client side I have a form that is submitted to a 'processFrom' function on the google app script server side when submitted. However the code got long and spaghetti like so I decided to just scratch it and start over. Essentially erased everything between the curly brackets. Now nothing will run inside the processForm function even just a simple Logger.log('in the function'); Won't log. I'm pretty baffled.

the client side button code that works when the old code is there:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Adding to list" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);formSubmitted();">
```

This is the server side that doesn't seem to process:

```
function processForm(formdata){
   Logger.log(formdata);
   Logger.log('in the loop');
}
```

Again I'd like to reiterate that all I did is delete spaghetti code from inside the curly brackets for processForm and all of the sudden it doesn't work. If I copy paste the spaghetti code back it miraculously works. By work I mean any code inside processForm starts to run and logg etc.

Update:

I went through the code in the functions processFrom and deleted line by line and check if the function is still working. The code is -

```
function processForm(formdata){
  Logger.log(formdata);
  var cSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFilesByName(formdata.Name);
  var spreadsheet = getListing();
}
```

This logs about one out of every four submits. If I take out the two variables I can't get formdata to log at all.

Update 2:

After more review I think I found the problem. The line is the problem (more specifically the formSubmitted() function):

```
onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);formSubmitted();"
```

In formSubmitted I have another call to google.script.run for something else, which overrides the google logs with nothing since in that function I do not have anything logging. The log only came up once in a while for processForm because I must have switched fast enough to the other tab and looked at the logs quickly before the formSubmitted function completed or ran.

Comment: Strange.  You don't have a second function named `processForm()` do you?  I've done that before, had duplicate function names.  From what you've shown, I don't see anything wrong.  But there must be an error somewhere in your code file.  Can you "manually" run that function?

Comment: No I only have two other functions so its not like the project is so big I couldn't find the duplicate. Also I've deleted line by line of the code until I have two variables that when I delete seem to make the function inoperable.

Comment: Forgot to answer your question. If I manually run the code it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

After more review I think I found the problem. The line is the problem (more specifically the formSubmitted() function):

onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);formSubmitted();"
In formSubmitted I have another call to google.script.run for something else, which overrides the google logs with nothing since in that function I do not have anything logging. The log only came up once in a while for processForm because I must have switched fast enough to the other tab and looked at the logs quickly before the formSubmitted function completed or ran.